# 9 VDC to 450 VDC circuit

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

I am trying to create a low-amperage circuit that can turn a DC voltage of around 8.3-12.0 V into 400-450 V DC for the purpose of charging a capacitor bank.

I do not need high amperage at all, as all I need is for the bank to be charged no matter how long it takes. Does anyone know of such a circuit I can buy, or a schematic to make one?

I looked around and I found something called a boost converter, or DC step-up circuit, but I can't find one in the range I'm looking for. I did find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWq1QORemW4) for exactly what I'm looking for. Is that a viable circuit?

Comment: What charging current at 450V.

Comment: Assuming your capacitor bank is a bunch of supercapacitors connected in series, could the individual capacitors be configured in parallel connection for charging? That would allow charging at a lower voltage. This is assuming sufficiently low resistance switches for reconfiguring the capacitor bank into series connection for the load application. Essentially the entire capacitor bank itself would become the final stage of a capacitive charge pump. Generally voltages higher than about 50VDC are considerably harder to work with.

Comment: You need to look for a disposable film camera with a flash. New they're only $10-20, used they would be free from a photo lab. They each have a 3 V to ~400 V inverter+transformer circuit to charge their flash capacitor. Mind your fingers.

Comment: @MarkU They are all in parallel not series; each cap is rated for 400v.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and fairly inexpensive and safe way to accomplish this might be an ordinary automotive 12V to 120 or 240 VAC inverter, connected to a step-up transformer (if needed) and bridge rectifier or voltage doubler using two or four diodes and capacitors, one of which would be the one you need to charge up. Here is an example:

[image: 240-650 VAC Doubler]

Using the usual "modified sine wave" which has peak voltage of 270 volts:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDC7J7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: Currents]